# If I wildshape into an earth elemental, what languages can I speak?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The druid class ability Wildshape says (among other things):

> A druid loses her ability to speak while in animal form because she is limited to the sounds that a normal, untrained animal can make, but she can communicate normally with other animals of the same general grouping as her new form. (The normal sound a wild parrot makes is a squawk, so changing to this form does not permit speech.)

Later on, the druid gains the ability to change into Elementals, in addition to Animals... But the rules are a little unclear as to what languages the druid can speak:

- Only Terran
- Only the druid's own languages
- Both the druid's languages and Terran

Elemental Body (the spell being emulated) doesn't seem to specify. Nor does the general Polymorph school.

On the one hand, there seems to be a pretty strong vibe of "you can't talk to the party while shifted."

On the other, the text refers to "animals" (elementals are outsiders), "sounds" (elementals don't "make sounds," they *speak*), "trained" (elementals are intelligent, and aren't "trained" in the same way an animal is, they *learn* new languages).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whatever languages you can normally speak.  Elementals can speak, so you can, too, unlike animals.  There's no mention in Wild Shape or any of the *elemental body* spells about gaining additional languages.